# gRPC open source License (MPL v2.0)

Tags: grpc

I have a question.

I can't find the source code for Mozilla Public license v2.0.

Which source code in the gRPC was distributed under the Mozilla Public license v2.0?

Answer (score 0):

The Mozilla Public License applies to the roots.pem file, which can be found [here in the gRPC GitHub repository](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/etc/roots.pem). The source of that file is described in [this README](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/etc/README.md).